# Single sign in for admin and user models using devise in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I have two models namely: Admin and User created using devise in ruby on rails. I want to have a single login page in the root for both user and admin;  also user sign up page should be in the same root page while admin will have a separate sign up page. This is similar to a facebook home page with login and sign up at the same page for general user and a separate sign up page for celebrity, band or business.

Please help.

My configurations:

1. Ruby version - 1.9.3
2. Rails version - 3.2.13
3. Devise version - 3.0.0

Comment: I have managed to solve the issue with the solutions provided [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299618/multiple-user-models-with-ruby-on-rails-and-devise-to-have-seperate-registration

Answer (score 0):

A single User model will be a good option for all user roles.

You can take another model as Role for different types of roles.

Role model

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :users    
end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :role
end
```

You can use [gem 'cancan'](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for role based authorization

For view part

On home page You can render different partials  for sign in and registration in different sections.

In home.html.erb

```
<%=render :partial => 'devise/sessions/form' %>
<%= render :partial => 'devise/registrations/form' %>
```

Comment: Having a single user model would be a bad idea in my case. The admin model has lots of fields to be filled up than in the user model.