# Devise, multiple user tables, one login path, multiple registration process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

Ok hello everyone,
I have been researching this subject for a while and have not found a solution that is specific to my needs.

**Requirements:**

- Multiple AR user tables (Administrators, Designers, Sponsors)
- I cannot use STI because each table can become fairly complex with multiple fields.
- They should all be able to login via the same path eg: www.domain.com/login/
- They should be able to register via different paths: eg.www.domain.com/designer/register
- They have different permissions
- After they are authenticated they should be redirected to their own area

Currently I have 3 devise models and each one can login to their own area e.g:
www.domain.com/designer/sign_in

Any idea on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest trying something like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299618/multiple-user-models-with-ruby-on-rails-and-devise-to-have-seperate-registration?rq=1

Comment: thank you @farleyknight that took care of it.