# How to write a create method for a user class with a polymorphic user model when using devise gem and Rails 4

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, strong-parameters

I'm following Vampire's solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299618/multiple-user-models-with-ruby-on-rails-and-devise-to-have-seperate-registration?rq=1) and am having some issues creating a new user with an associated child class.

I have a user model with a polymorphic association to two child classes, student and editor. New user registration has its own controller as well. When I fill out my form I get an error stating that email and password cannot be blank, even though they are not. How do I write the create method to accept attributes from one of two possible child classes.

Editor Model

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
class Editor < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :user, :as => :rolable
  belongs_to :school
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

User Model (not sure if I need to be using accepts nested attributes here or not)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  belongs_to :rolable, :polymorphic => true
  has_many :editors
  has_many :students 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :editors  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :students

  #has_many :applications 
  #has_many :editors, :through => :applications
  #has_and_belongs_to_many :schools 
end
```

New user form

```
<center>
<div class="hero-unit">
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<% params[:user][:user_type] ||= 'student'

  if ["student", "editor"].include? params[:user][:user_type].downcase
    child_class_name = params[:user][:user_type].downcase.camelize
    user_type = params[:user][:user_type].downcase
  else
    child_class_name = "Student"
    user_type = "student"
  end

  resource.rolable = child_class_name.constantize.new if resource.rolable.nil?

%>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
 <%= my_devise_error_messages! %>


  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>


  <%= fields_for resource.rolable do |rf| %>
    <% render :partial => "#{child_class_name.underscore}_fields", :locals => { :f => rf } %>
  <% end %>

  <%= hidden_field :user, :user_type, :value => user_type %>


  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
</center>
```

User registrations controller

```
class UserRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,) 
  end


  def new
    super
  end

  def update
    super
  end

  def edit
    super
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end 

  def create

    # Building the user, I assume.
    build_resource

    # crate a new child instance depending on the given user type
    child_class = params[:user][:user_type].camelize.constantize
    resource.rolable = child_class.new(user_params[child_class.to_s.underscore.to_sym])

    # first check if child instance is valid
    # cause if so and the parent instance is valid as well
    # it's all being saved at once
    valid = resource.valid?
    valid = resource.rolable.valid? && valid

    # customized code end

    if valid && resource.save    # customized code
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :inactive_signed_up, :reason => inactive_reason(resource) if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }

    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

def create

```
# Building the user, I assume.
build_resource (**sign_up_params**)
```

you are missing the sign_up_params