# Rails 4.1 User registration with polymorphic associations for multiple roles using devise ForbiddenAttributes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, polymorphic-associations

I'am new in Rails so i start learning it since Rails 4. I had to make 2 types of users - client and companies, so i decide to use polymorphic associations for it. Now i am trying to make registration and authentication for these models with devise`(ver. 3.4.0)`. I was looking for solutions here and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299618/multiple-user-models-with-ruby-on-rails-and-devise-to-have-separate-registration) but as i understand it works only on Rails 3. On Rails 4 I can't solve problem with permited attributes and I keep getting an error `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

## User Model

#### Schema

```
t.string   "email",                 
t.string   "encrypted_password",   
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",      
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "confirmation_token"
t.datetime "confirmed_at"
t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "role_type"
t.integer  "role_id"
```

#### Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  belongs_to :role, :polymorphic => true
end
```

## Client Model

#### Schema

```
t.string   "client_name"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

#### Model

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :role
end
```

## Company Model

#### Schema

```
t.string   "company_name"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "company_tel"
```

#### Model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :role
end
```

Then I created a custom views and registartion controller for devise and put it in `routs.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
  resources :users

  devise_scope :user do 
    get 'client/sign_up' => 'registrations#new', :user => { :user_type => 'client' }
    get 'company/sign_up' => 'registrations#new', :user => { :user_type => 'company' }
  end
```

Registration view

```
#views/registration/new.html.erb
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%
  # customized code begin

  params[:user][:user_type] ||= 'client'

  if ["client", "company"].include? params[:user][:user_type].downcase
    child_class_name = params[:user][:user_type].downcase.camelize
    user_type = params[:user][:user_type].downcase
  else
    child_class_name = "Client"
    user_type = "client"
  end

  resource.role = child_class_name.constantize.new if resource.role.nil?

  # customized code end
%>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <% my_devise_error_messages!    # customized code %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <% # customized code begin %>
  <%= fields_for resource.role do |rf| %>
    <% render :partial => "#{child_class_name.underscore}_fields", :locals => { :f => rf } %>
  <% end %>

  <%= hidden_field :user, :user_type, :value => user_type %>
  <% # customized code end %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

This form include partial for additional fields depending on the type of user

For client

```
#views/registration/_client_fields.html.erb
<div><%= f.label :client_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :client_name %></div>
```

For company

```
#views/registration/_company_fields.html.erb
<div><%= f.label :company_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :company_name %></div>

<div><%= f.label :company_tel %><br />
<%= f.text_field :company_tel %></div>
```

Custon devise registration controller

```
#controllers/registration_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    user_params        = sign_up_params # is sign_up_params not able to edit?
    user_type          = user_params.delete (:user_type) #take out user_type from user_params
    child_class_params = user_params.delete (user_type.to_s.underscore.to_sym) #obtain a nested hash (:company or :client)

    logger.debug "sign_up_params: #{sign_up_params}"         #DEBUG
    logger.debug "user_params: #{user_params}"               #DEBUG
    logger.debug "user_type: #{user_type}"                   #DEBUG
    logger.debug "child_class_params: #{child_class_params}" #DEBUG

    build_resource(user_params)

    # crate a new child instance depending on the given user type
    child_class = user_type.camelize.constantize

    resource.role = child_class.new(child_class_params)

    # first check if child instance is valid
    # cause if so and the parent instance is valid as well
    # it's all being saved at once
    valid = resource.valid?
    valid = resource.role.valid? && valid

    # customized code end

    if valid && resource.save    # customized code
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
      if @validatable
        @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
      end
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
end
```

Now I need to permit params and nested params for company or client so I did so:

```
#controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| 
        u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_type).tap do |wl| 
            if params[:company]
              wl[:company] = params[:company]
            elsif params[:client]
              wl[:client]  = params[:client]
            end
        end 
    }
  end
end
```

All params are passed to the controller but I think something wrong with permit company and client nested params becouse still have `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in RegistrationsController#create` on line

```
resource.role = child_class.new(child_class_params)
```

---

**Debug info:**

```
sign_up_params: {"email"=>"example@expample.com", "password"=>"12345678", "password_confirmation"=>"12345678", "user_type"=>"company", "company"=>{"company_name"=>"expample company name", "company_tel"=>"223-2323-2"}}
user_params: {"email"=>"example@expample.com", "password"=>"12345678", "password_confirmation"=>"12345678"}
user_type: company
child_class_params: {"company_name"=>"expample company name", "company_tel"=>"223-2323-2"}
```

You can see that all the necessary params are passed to the controller via `sign_up_params`
then why there is an error `ForbiddenAttributes`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved, it may be useful to someone
I still do not understand what the problem was but I did this:

```
resource.role = child_class.new(child_class_params.symbolize_keys)
```

and it started working without errors.