# Setting up different User models and registration paths for Devise on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, rolify

I am very new to ruby and I have been really struggling with this for months. I searched extensively and tried what the answers said but still no luck. (I tried [Multiple user models with Ruby On Rails and devise to have separate registration routes but one common login route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299618/multiple-user-models-with-ruby-on-rails-and-devise-to-have-separate-registration) but didnt work)

I currently have a user.rb model and it is connected to devise and works fine.

1- On the sign-up page, I would like to have 3 buttons that would lead to separate registration forms (one each for business, manager and the already existing user). Do I set this up in routes.rb?
2- The forms will have different attributes that will populate their respective databases. 
3- After completion of the form they will be directed to their respective routes. User to the current default route while business to the business dashboard and manager to the manager dashboard. Is this again in routes.rb or devise?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance!

I've read through the documentations for devise, cancan and rolify but I can't seem to bring it all together to work for me.

I am very new to ruby and I have been really struggling with this for months. I searched extensively and tried what the answers said but still no luck. (I tried [Multiple user models with Ruby On Rails and devise to have separate registration routes but one common login route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299618/multiple-user-models-with-ruby-on-rails-and-devise-to-have-separate-registration) but didnt work)

I currently have a user.rb model and it is connected to devise and works fine.

1- On the sign-up page, I would like to have 3 buttons that would lead to separate registration forms (one each for business, manager and the already existing user). Do I set this up in routes.rb?
2- The forms will have different attributes that will populate their respective databases. 
3- After completion of the form they will be directed to their respective routes. User to the current default route while business to the business dashboard and manager to the manager dashboard. Is this again in routes.rb or devise?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance!

I've read through the documentations for devise, cancan and rolify but I can't seem to bring it all together to work for me.

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :contibutions

rolify
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :lockable, :timeoutable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

validates_format_of :email, :without => TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX, on: :update

def admin?
  has_role?(:admin)
end

def self.find_for_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)

# Get the identity and user if they exist
identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)
user = identity.user
if user.nil?

  # Get the existing user from email if the OAuth provider gives us an email
  user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first if auth.info.email

  # Create the user if it is a new registration
  if user.nil?
    user = User.new(
      name: auth.extra.raw_info.name,
      #username: auth.info.nickname || auth.uid,
      email: auth.info.email.blank? ? TEMP_EMAIL : auth.info.email,
      password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    )
    user.skip_confirmation!
    user.save!
  end

  # Associate the identity with the user if not already
  if identity.user != user
    identity.user = user
    identity.save!
  end
end
user
end
end
```

Comment: you'll need to share the code you have set up and I can tell you from experience this can be done but there are a lot of moving parts.  In my opinion this question is too broad.

Comment: Which files would I need to share? routes.rb?

Comment: Personally I found multiple devise user models to a massive pain. After that experience I went with single model, using the 'easy roles' gem, then having seperate account models for each user type. easy_roles is outdated though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with one User model and a two stage signup. First they would click on their desired button, each one passing a unique 'role' param in the URL and going to the devise signup page. Here they would enter only their email/password and we would pass the param from the URL to a simple 'role' hidden field in the form.

Then as step 2, after technically registering, they are directed to a separate edit account type page (each user having a different account, outlined below) to fill in the rest of their details.

The models:

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
  has_one :business_account
  has_one :manager_account
end
```

models/account.rb

```
class Account
  belongs_to :user
```

models/business_account.rb

```
class BusinessAccount
  belongs_to :user
```

models/manager_account.rb

```
class ManagerAccount
  belongs_to :user
```

Then, using devise, I'd override the registrations_controller to add a role based on a hidden field in the first step simple registration form (which would just be email/password/role).

In that file, I'd also override the after_signup_path method, to redirect to an edit_account type page for the relevant account we create for them during signup.

First the routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}

resources :users do 
  resource :account
  resource :business_account
  resource :manager_account
end
```

Then the controller (see comments within code):

controllers/registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save

      # you will name the following param. make sure it's in devise strong_params
      # also the == will depend on how you pass the role - string, integer etc

      if sign_up_params[:role] == "1"
        user.add_role :standard
        resource.build_account(user_id: resource.id) # code to create user account
      elsif sign_up_params[:role] == "2"
        user.add_role :manager
        resource.build_manager_account(user_id: resource.id) # code to create user account
      elsif sign_up_params[:role] == "2"
        user.add_role :business
        resource.build_business_account(user_id: resource.id) # code to create user account
      end

      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  protected

  # override the after signup path to your desired route, e.g
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    if sign_up_params[:role] == "1"
      edit_user_account_path(resource.id)
    elsif sign_up_params[:role] == "2"
      edit_user_manager_account_path(resource.id)
    elsif sign_up_params[:role] == "2"
      edit_user_business_account_path(resource.id)
    end 
  end
end
```

The above would redirect them to a separate accounts controller/view depending on the account type. This solution would save you a lot of headaches down the line.