# Multiple user models with Ruby On Rails and devise to have separate registration but one common login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i have same problem just like this link:

[Multiple user models with Ruby On Rails and devise to have separate registration routes but one common login route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299618/multiple-user-models-with-ruby-on-rails-and-devise-to-have-separate-registration)

in my app there are two model

1. Company
2. Employee

my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :usr, :polymorphic => true
end
```

my Company model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :as => :usr
end
```

my Employee model

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :as => :usr
end
```

app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%
  # customized code begin

  params[:user][:user_type] ||= 'company'

  if ["company", "employee"].include? params[:user][:user_type].downcase
    child_class_name = params[:user][:user_type].downcase.camelize
    user_type = params[:user][:user_type].downcase
  else
    child_class_name = "Company"
    user_type = "company"
  end

  resource.usr = child_class_name.constantize.new if resource.usr.nil?

  # customized code end
%>



<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @validatable %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>


  <% # customized code begin %>
  <%= fields_for resource.usr do |rf| %>
    <% render :partial => "#{child_class_name.underscore}_fields", :locals => { :f => rf } %>
  <% end %>

  <%= hidden_field :user, :user_type, :value => user_type %>
  <% # customized code end %>



  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

my registration create method :

controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 def create
    build_resource

    # customized code begin

    # crate a new child instance depending on the given user type
    child_class = params[:user][:user_type].camelize.constantize
    resource.usr = child_class.new(params[child_class.to_s.underscore.to_sym])

    # first check if child instance is valid
    # cause if so and the parent instance is valid as well
    # it's all being saved at once
    valid = resource.valid?
    valid = resource.usr.valid? && valid

    # customized code end

    if valid && resource.save    # customized code
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :inactive_signed_up, :reason => inactive_reason(resource) if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

my application helper file :

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def my_devise_error_messages!
    return "" if resource.errors.empty? && resource.usr.errors.empty?

    messages = usr_messages = ""

    if !resource.errors.empty?
      messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    end

    if !resource.usr.errors.empty?
      usr_messages = resource.usr.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    end

    messages = messages + usr_messages   
    sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                      :count => resource.errors.count + resource.usr.errors.count,
                      :resource => resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
    <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

but i got error something like this when i open any user sign_up page:

```
localhost:3000/emloyees/sign_up **OR**

localhost:3000/companies/sign_up
```

error in registration view

ERROR :-

[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really broad but to solve the error you posted, it is erroring undefined method because of the nested hash that doesn't exist.  Here's the example:

```
[1] pry(main)> params = {}
=> {}
[2] pry(main)> params[:user]
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> params[:user][:user_type]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

If your code is to expect that params[:user] won't ever exist without a `user_type` and you want to default that to company, then that would simply be:

```
[7] pry(main)> params[:user] ||= { user_type: "company" }
=> {:user_type=>"company"}
[8] pry(main)> params
=> {:user=>{:user_type=>"company"}}
```

Alternativley if you want to just return a string if params[:user] doesn't exist, you can use ||= or [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) with a default value.  Hash#fetch is a safer way to error handle imo.

```
[5] pry(main)> params.fetch(:user, "company")
=> "company"
```

Comment: my params[:user] not gives "nil" but gives error "undefined local variable or method `params' for #<ActionView::Template::Error:0xb05ba58>" actually i not get params in registration new page. i don't know why. i think you have to refer link which i mention in starting of question so you are more clear. thanks